# How can i add new javascript file in odoo 11.0 and call the script on load of web/login?

Tags: javascript, odoo-11

i am working with odoo 11.0 community edition, i want to call a script on Load of web/login view of odoo. How can i do that, is it possible ?

Comment: Let's say you want the script to be activated only when user comes from sign-up page to the thank-you then you could just add a conditional stateent to the script:
if(window.location.pathname == "/page/thank-you" &amp;&amp; document.referrer.indexOf('/web/signup') != -1)
Otherwise, simply follow instructions from upvoted answer

Answer (score 1):

```
<template id="assets_login" inherit_id="web.assets_frontend">
    <xpath expr="." position="inside">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/website_issue_form/static/src/js/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Comment: what to do with it ? i am basically new with odoo

Answer (score 0):

I prefer as a new in odoo you read this default odoo document : 
[Odoo JS Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/javascript_reference.html)

From this you might get idea how to done with JS  in odoo